# R code: what does this combination of %in% and <- do?

Tags: r

```
data[data[["Id"]] %in% current[["Id"]], "Type"] <- "TRANS"
```

I'm confused, because there seems to be a conditional expression: 
`data[data[["Id"]] %in% current[["Id"]], "Type"]` combined with an assignment of a string: `<- "TRANS"`

Comment: It's an assignment **of** the string `"TRANS"`.

Comment: It is replacing the `"Type"` column of `data` for rows where any value of `current[["Id"]]` is present in `data[["Id"]]` with `"TRANS"`.

Comment: do yourself a favor and use intermediate variables: `idx <- data[["Id"]] %in% current[["Id"]]`. now examine `idx`. the next line then becomes more readable: `data[idx, 'Type'] <- 'TRANS'`

Answer (score 1):

This is called “subassignment”. When `data[i, j]` is placed on the left-hand-side of `<-`, the subset of `data` selected is replaced with the right-hand-side of `<-`. Or, rephrased as in the docs:

```
help('[')
```

> Indexing can occur on the right-hand-side of an expression for
>   extraction, or on the left-hand-side for replacement. When an index
>   expression appears on the left side of an assignment (known as
>   subassignment) then that part of x is set to the value of the right
>   hand side of the assignment

So what's happening here is due to `[]` and `<-` being combined and it would take place regardless of the function (`%in%`, `seq`, `+`, etc.) used to produce the `i` or `j` part of `data[i, j]`. The fact that `%in%` is used doesn't really have any impact here because it does same thing it would do without the assignment `<-`, i.e. produce a logical vector.